# Getting this error "syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ';' " in Laravel while creating simple controller

Tags: php, laravel, syntax, controller, routes

Hey I just start to learn Laravel. I have created Controller successfully with php artisan make:controller Youtube command. But the thing is when i try to access it from Route which look like this **"Route::get("/Youtube","Youtube@index");"** While there is simple echo statement in controller. **Controller look like this**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class Youtube extends Controller
{
    function index(){
      echo "create";
    }
}
```

Comment: Add trace. Perhaps this will be a duplicate question.

Comment: Ist that the **full** file triggering that error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add, `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` before class and make the function as public This should work fine.

You just included namespace.

Comment: Useless statement `use`, because controllers in the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, `YoutubeController` insted of `Youtube`. And URL should be lowercase.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class YoutubeController extends Controller
{
    function index(){
      dd('create');
    }
}
```

```
Route::get("/youtube","YoutubeController@index");
```